# is it possible to enable client certificate authentication in EKS?

Tags: authentication, kubernetes, amazon-iam, amazon-eks

Searching through the Internet, I have seen that EKS only enables IAM authentication for IAM users.
Is it possible to configure client certificate authentication manually? I mean, create Kubernetes users and roles internally and not use IAM authentication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kubernetes supports several authentication modules, for example:

- X509 client certificates
- Service account tokens
- OpenID Connect tokens
- Webhook token authentication
- Authenticating proxy, etc.

You can find more details regarding them in the [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/).

However, Amazon EKS uses only one specific authentication method, an implementation of a webhook token authentication to authenticate Kube API requests. This webhook service is implemented by an open source tool called AWS IAM Authenticator, which has both client and server sides.

In short, the client sends a token (which includes the AWS IAM identity—user or role—making the API call) which is verified on the server-side by the webhook service.

So the answer to your question is: if you choose to use EKS you only have one authentication option which is IAM.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Sure, thank you very much for your answer. It helps a lot, confirming that only IAM is supported in AWS EKS.

Comment: worth noting that EKS does support at least one additional authentication type, which is service account tokens :) (not that you should use them for end-user auth. but it is a possibility). You can also use the TokenRequest API although EKS does limit those tokens to a 24 hour lifetime.

Comment: There's also a possibility to authenticate using OpenID Connect (OIDC) external providers - [EKS doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/authenticate-oidc-identity-provider.html).